# PHP Script mkdir "No error, but no directory"

Tags: php, html, directory

I am currently learning and messing around with some HTML and PHP on my personal website. I need to create a "New Directory" using PHP.

I am currently using, http://dummycode.com/projects/projectform/form.html in order to try and make this happen. It is running the PHP script but it is not creating a new directory under `/projects/projectform/dir`

Here is the code for the form.php file:

```
    <?php
$result = mkdir("http://dummycode.com/projects/projectform/dir", 0700);
if ($result == 1) {
    echo "Success creating directory!";
} else {
    echo "Error creating directory!";
}

?>
```

I cannot seem to find the issue because every time it says "Error creating directory!" but the PHP is not throwing any errors.

Is there something simple I am missing, or am I just being stupid?

Thanks,
Henry Harris

Comment: Have you got PHP error reporting turned on?

Comment: I believe so... Nothing is being thrown but it is not being created.

Comment: How about your privilage in  ../projects/projectform .. ?

Comment: @matzone What do you mean by privilege?

Comment: 755 is my CHMOD value... If that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a relative path rather then a url?

Answer (score 2):

While PHP 5 introduced support for protocol wrappers, the support is not universal, as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

> 5.0.0 As of PHP 5.0.0 `mkdir()` can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a listing of which wrappers support `mkdir()`.

The HTTP protocol is not supported by `mkdir`, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php):

```
Wrapper Summary
Attribute                                   Supported
---------------------------------------     ---------
Restricted by allow_url_fopen               Yes
Allows Reading                              Yes
Allows Writing                              No
Allows Appending                            No
Allows Simultaneous Reading and Writing     N/A
Supports stat()                             No
Supports unlink()                           No
Supports rename()                           No
Supports mkdir()                            No   <----
Supports rmdir()                            No
```

If you want to make a directory, you'll need to do it using a proper (filesystem-based) file specification rather than a URL.

What's *possibly* happening is that a directory is being created, it's just that it'll be called `http://dummycode.com/projects/projectform/dir` and exist in whatever your default directory was when you executed the `mkdir`. That would explain why there's no error and why the directory doesn't appear to come into existence. I'd have a look into that.

However, that's tangential to the problem, which can be solved by not using a URL.

Comment: I have figure it out, if I do $result = mkdir("dir"); It creates a directory called "dir" under projectform